# How can i treat multiple exception one after one in PHP?

Tags: php

I wrote some code but this way i can only treat one exception per insertion attempt. Then in front end the user
needs click insert again to know if another thing is invalid, like password. How can i treat 
this case properly?

```
<?php


$user = new User();

$user->setUser('test');
$user->setPassword('test');

try{
    $user->insert();
}catch(UserAlreadyExistsException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}catch(InvalidUserException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}catch(InvalidPasswordException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}



class User{
    private $user;
    private $password;

    function setUser($user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }

    function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    function getPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }


    function insert(){
        if (strlen($this->getUser()) == 255){
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException('User already exists in database. Please choose another', 1);
        }

        if (strlen($this->getUser()) > 2){
            throw new InvalidUserException('Invalid username. Please make sure username contains only A-Z and a maximum of 32 characters', 1);
        }

        if (strlen($this->getPassword()) > 2){
            throw new InvalidPasswordException('Invalid password. Please make sure password contains a maximum of 128 characters', 1);
        }

    }

}

class UserAlreadyExistsException extends Exception{

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }

    public function customFunction() {
        echo "";
    }
}

class InvalidUserException extends Exception{

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }

    public function customFunction() {
        echo "";
    }
}

class InvalidPasswordException extends Exception{

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }

    public function customFunction() {
        echo "";
    }
}

?>
```

I Expect the output of all invalid things like:
Invalid username. Please make sure username contains only A-Z and a maximum of 32 characters

Invalid password. Please make sure password contains a maximum of 128 characters'

But the actual output just display one per one exception like:
Invalid username. Please make sure username contains only A-Z and a maximum of 32 characters

Comment: You may be better off doing the user/password validation when you call the `setUser()` and `setPassword()` methods as you can't raise more than 1 exception in a chain like this.

Comment: Or you can make a "multi reason" exception - an exception that holds multiple exceptions (e.g. each one being a failed validstion).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply not use exceptions and instead push the name of the problematic field and the relevant error message into an array - and then return this array to the frontend. Thus it will know exactly which form fields have an issue and properly position the error messages on the screen.